# Import from one mysql db to another

Tags: mysql, import, compare

Hoping if anyone can give me some pointers or open source tools.

What I hoping is possible is this I have two mysql database and both have the same structure. I want to compare tables from dB A with dB B. Both DBs are slightly different in terms of added information so I want any information that's not in dB B but is in dB A to be imported into dB B without removing any information from dB B. The only thing I can see causing me issues is if an ID in dB B matches that in dB A but the rest of the record is different like a username and password etc. So if importing the code can this be automatically fixed by checking what the latest ID is in dB B and the ID changed to be the next in line in terms of number then add the rest of the missing information?

I hope I have explained this to the best of my ability.

Nothing as yet as I'm not all that experienced with mysql

Comment: Are the two databases within the same mysql instance?

Answer (score 0):

There is FEDERATED engine available which allow check for table from another DB. After that, you can compare using join.

Another option is to export table to csv on both and use diff utility. Do that without ID column and will be no problem. After that add ID column.

But correct solution is another one for task like that. You need ensure that IDs which were inserted in both tables do not overlap. See **auto_increment_offset**